# Turning off Live Updates by default in Layout Inspector

Tags: android, android-studio, settings, updates, layout-inspector

I recently updated Android Studio and the update included some new features for Layout Inspector. There is now a live updates checkbox that seems to be turned ON by default when running the debugger. Unfortunately, my app slows down to a crawl while this is active so I need to check off the feature every time after the app starts, which is a lot. I would like to know if there is a setting to keep live updates off by default instead of on. Thank you!

[image: Live Updates CheckBox]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable **Live Layout Inspector** by unchecking the **Enable Live Layout Inspector** box under the **Layout Inspector** header in the **Experimental section**. [Screenshot of Android Studio Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnAbf.png)

Note: I'm currently on Android Studio 4.1-RC version and have no elected to update to the latest stable version so the exact details may change depending on what A.S. version you're on.

Comment: You can still inspect your layouts with Legacy Layout Inspector (Tools > Legacy Layout Inspector as of AS 4.1-RS). Works fine without slowing down your app.

Comment: Thanks. On AS stable channel 4.1.3 , it's `Tools > Layout Inspector`, OR `Tools > Legacy Layout Inspector`, according to whether *Enable Live Layout Inspector* is checked.